# Matching a file's string length with a file's integer

Tags: string, file, integer, ada

I've been working with file assignments and happend on a tricky problem where I need to read a file's numbers and match them by comparing the first integer to the second one, separated by a space. If the latter number is higher than the number of constituents in the former I'm supposed to print them out.

```
      Create(F, Out_File, File_Name);
      Put_Line(F, "23709 5");
      Put_Line(F, "001 4");
      Put_Line(F, "1 1");
      Put_Line(F, "10923487283462 14");
      Put_Line(F, "22 3");
```

In the above scenario, which is the real problem, Id want to print lines

```
001 4
22 3
```

because they mismatch.

Originally I planned to solve this by adding a Check variable that would be equal to 10 ** checksum (the latter integer above) -1. That would work unless it werent so that the fourth number is too big to be read and so I chose to go down the path of making the first integer a string and trying to match it's length with the checksum integer. Here's where I ran into problems. My way of naming the string stores numbers from previous lines and builds on them unfortunately. And because they build on each other my check variable doesnt work because its not matched to the actual length of the string but the combined length of the string and then some.

Here's my code:

```
with ada.text_IO; use ada.text_IO;
with ada.integer_text_IO; use ada.integer_text_IO;
with ada.float_text_IO; use ada.float_text_IO;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Im supposed to read the following file and detect
-- whether or not the integer in the file following immediately after
-- the space indicates how many integer places are found
-- in the integer infront of the space. If it mismatches
-- Im supposed to print it.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure exercise2 is

   F: File_Type;
   File_Name: constant String := "BAD_DIGITS.TXT";
   Space : Character;
   Checksum: Integer;
   Name : String(1..20);
   L: Integer := 0;
   Ints : Integer;
   Char : Character;

   begin

      Create(F, Out_File, File_Name);
      Put_Line(F, "23709 5");
      Put_Line(F, "001 4");
      Put_Line(F, "1 1");
      Put_Line(F, "10923487283462 14");
      Put_Line(F, "22 3");

      Close(F);

      Open(F, In_File, File_Name);

      while not End_Of_File(F) loop
     while not End_Of_Line(F) loop
        loop
           Get(F, Char);
           L := L+1;
           if Char = ' ' then
          exit;
           else
          Name(L) := Char;
           end if;
        end loop;
        Get(F, Checksum);
        if L-1 > Checksum then
           Put(Name);
           Put(" ");
           Put(Checksum, Width =>0);
           New_Line;
           L := 0;
        end if;
     end loop;
     Skip_Line(F);
      end loop;




end exercise2;
```

I've been sitting all day with this problem and I'm hoping someone comes along with some constructive feedback to free my mind.

Comment: Try reading the input one character at a time. Count all the digits read before the space then compare that count to the numeric value of the digit(s) after the space.

Comment: At first glance, you need to move the line `L := 0;` so it takes effect for all completed lines, not just the ones that you print out. I’d put it in between the two `while` lines so it’s more obvious what’s going on. Also, are you sure about the test `if L-1 > Checksum then`?

Comment: I would suggest reading an entire line into a `String`. Find the start of the first number, using `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index_Non_Blank`. Find the space after the first number, using `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index`. Convert the slice of the string after the space to an `Integer` using `Integer'Value`. Compare the value obtained to the length of the slice containing the first number. Perform error checking as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you zero your character counter before reading each line.
Only increment your character counter if the character is not a space.
Read the checksum value as an integer.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   F: File_Type;
   File_Name: constant String := "BAD_DIGITS.TXT";
   Space : constant Character :=  ' ';
   Checksum: Integer;
   Value : String(1..20);
   L: Integer := 0;
   Char : Character;
begin
   Create(F, Out_File, File_Name);
   Put_Line(F, "23709 5");
   Put_Line(F, "001 4");
   Put_Line(F, "1 1");
   Put_Line(F, "10923487283462 14");
   Put_Line(F, "22 3");

   Close(F);

   Open(F, In_File, File_Name);

   while not End_Of_File(F) loop
      L := 0;
      loop
         Get(File => F,
             Item => Char);
         if Char /= Space then
            L := L + 1;
            Value(L) := Char;
         else
            exit;
         end if;
      end loop;
      Get(F, Checksum);  -- Uses Ada.Integer_Text_Io
      if Checksum /= L then
         Put_Line(Value(1..L) & Checksum'Image);
      end if;

   end loop;
 end main;
```

Comment: We should not be doing students' homework for them.

Comment: While my answer provides correct results it will not fulfill all the requirements imposed by his instructor. Namely, it does not encapsulate the algorithm into its own function or procedure. Encapsulating the algorithm into its own function or procedure will require some re-arrangement of data, which I assume will be a challenge to the student.

Comment: I see nothing in the post to indicate a requirement to encapsulate the algorithm into a subprogram. Developing the algorithm appears to be the purpose of the assignment.